# php7 fpm sock file ownership on service restart

Tags: php, debian

I have just installed PHP7
https://github.com/kasparsd/php-7-debian

Everything works except each time I do `service php7-fpm restart` I need manually to set ownership on file `/run/php7-fpm.sock` to `www-data`

After setting the permissions everything works.. But how to avoid this on every restart?

The ownership is always `root` after restart

## php-fpm.ini

```
user = www-data
group = www-data
```

Comment: You are changing the ownership - not the permissions. What was it before you changed it? (if it were me I'd put the webserver uid and fpm uid in a common group, and set the umask and sg appropriately in the fpm startup script.

Comment: the ownership is always `root`

Comment: That's just the user ownership - group ownership is important too. But that you are having to change it, rather implies you are running PHP-FPM as root. While this is a requirement for running pools with different ownerships, if you only have a single ownership pool, it shouldn't be running as root, changing the runtime to www-data in php-fpm.conf ("user www-data") should solve your problem. DO NOT USE SUDO.

Comment: Sorry - should be `listen.owner` and `listen.group` which determine the permissions on the file (user and group are the runtime).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ownership of the file socket is determined by the `listen.owner` and `listen.group` directives in the F[PM config file](http://php.net/manual/en/install.fpm.configuration.php).

Answer (score 0):

If thats your local development environment, just add www-data to the sudo. That should make things easy.

Also try reinstalling PHP

Following tutorial might be helpful.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-upgrade-to-php-7-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: My bad. I use Vagrant for PHP development. Less hazzle since its on a Virtual environment of its own. However if you add www-data to sudo it should work.